# Campagnolo Athena 9 speed compatibility?

Tags: road-bike, shifter, speed, campagnolo, brake-levers

I own some NOS shifters, Campy Athena 9 speed, from 1998 i guess.
do you guys know if I can use it with any campagnolo front/rear derailleur?
how do I know what is compatible?

Answer (score 2):

This page is incredibly useful for figuring this stuff out. Campy shifters with just about any front derailleur should be fine since they have micro trim.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bicycles/Maintenance_and_Repair/Gear-changing_Dimensions#REAR_SHIFTING_TABLES

Answer (score 1):

You will need a pre-2000 rear derailleur as the cable pull ratio was changed in MY2001 and the lever / rear derailleur movement artio, if you use a current 9/10s RD will not give you accurate indexing.

You can use and front derailleur from Campagnolo describing itself as "9/10s" compatible but you may find that you need to set it up with more care as the most recent 9/10s FDs have a different movement to cable recovery ratio, too - this is not such a big problem on the FD as it is on the rear, because you are not aiming for such exact index points but it can still be a consideration.

As the main Campagnolo factory-appointed Warranty and Service Centre for the UK, we can assure you that the above answer is correct.